# Regex to make search suggestion bold like Google or Amazon

Tags: javascript, highlight

I'm looking for solution to make text bold, like Google and Amazon search suggesters do it.

I know how to make it the opposite way (if I type "ne"), e.g. **Ne**wton with function like this:

```
    highlight(value, input): string {
    return value.replace(new RegExp('(^|)(' + input + ')(|$)', 'ig'), '$1<b>$2</b>$3');
}
```

But how should this regex look to achieve this; for example, if I type "ne" I should get:

1. ne**w car**
2. **Super** ne**w computer**
3. Ne**wton**

Comment: Do you in fact have spaces in the alternations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Regex you're using here covers all of your use cases, a simple solution would be to leave it (almost) exactly as it is, and modify the CSS for the desired effect:

```css
.search-suggestion { font-weight: bold; }
.search-suggestion > span { font-weight: normal; }
```

Put your search suggestion in an element that has the `search-suggestion` class, and modify your Regex to wrap the search text in a `<span>` instead of a `<b>` element.

Comment: oh nice idea. Thanks for this simple solution